# Function as a callback reloads without respecting the event listener while using arrow-function gives intended behaviour. Why is it so?

Tags: javascript, function, arrow-functions

### Goal

Console must log a message **only** on clicking the button.

---

### Set-up

```
const button_l = document.querySelector('.btn-left');
```

method-1 **(Using arrow function as a callback)**

```
button_l.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('I am in')
});
```

method-2 **(Using function as a callback)**

```
button_l.addEventListener('click', changeSlide());

function changeSlide() {
    console.log('Am I globally present?');
}
```

---

### Problem Facing

1. Using method-1 gives the desired results.
2. Using method-2, the function is called on page load, but when I remove the parentheses (**from changeSlide() to changeSlide**), it functions as it should, why is it so?

---

I think it is something very fundamentally obvious that I do not know.

I appreciate a link/reference to any helpful theory/understanding.

Comment: `button_l.addEventListener('click', changeSlide());` -> `button_l.addEventListener('click', changeSlide);` remove the `()` at the end, otherwise you immediately call the function.

Comment: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/why-do-we-call-the-functions-without-parentheses-ie

Comment: Thankyou @AyushSingh

I was calling the function and not referencing it.
I have a fragmented understanding now, I'll read more about it. :)